# How to dynamically click on Textbox using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

This is my html

```
  <div class="main" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
       <div " ng-show="showhide"><input type="text" class="textbox ></div>
       <div ng-click="showtext()">click</div>
  </div>
```

When i click on click ,i have to show textbox and that textbox should be clicked one so

This is my controller

```
  app.controller('mainCtrl',function($scope)
 {
      $scope.showtext=function($scope)
      {
          $scope.showhide=true;
          angular.element.find('.textbox').click();

      }
 });
```

but this is not working so How to do that in angularjs?

Comment: angularjs not proposal operating elements in controller.you can do this in custome directives.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do `angular.element(".textbox").trigger("click");`